# How to write solve(X'X) in R more succinctly?

Tags: r, shortcut

I think I remember seeing a shorthand for `solve(t(X) %*% X)` in R, but I can't remember what it was. Is there something like that? Just a way to do that in fewer keystrokes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of `crossprod()`? It's not fewer keystrokes, but is a bit more elegant and, [according to its help file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/crossprod.html), it can be slightly faster than the naive construction.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(9), ncol=3)
solve(crossprod(x))
#             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.34638151 -0.02957435  0.8010735
# [2,] -0.02957435  0.32780020 -0.1786295
# [3,]  0.80107345 -0.17862950  1.4533671
solve(t(x) %*% x)
#             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.34638151 -0.02957435  0.8010735
# [2,] -0.02957435  0.32780020 -0.1786295
# [3,]  0.80107345 -0.17862950  1.4533671
```

Comment: In addition to readability and speed, one might be concerned with precision. The usual recommendation is to avoid computing the inverse of X'X explicitly if one is only interested in the OLS estimator. See "Least Squares Calculations in R" by Doug Bates in R News 2004(1), 17-20. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: @Achim Very good point. Nine times out of ten that is why someone will be wanting the inverse of X'X,  isn't it?  Thanks too for leaving the link to the Bates article.